# How to configure Mongodb with Laravel 5.4?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, builder

I tried to install "jenssegers/laravel-mongodb" from git 
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb
and all the configuration has been done. but how can I know that my Laravel project successfully connected to MongoDB database?

Comment: Why not create a database, a collection and a document, and then write some code to read that document?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed mongo? if not, here's a guide:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

if you want to try if it works, simply try to save something to the db using eloquent.

Just remember that in your model, extend "Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model" instead of "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model"